# Present perfect +passive

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

Why do we use "been" in present perfect passive tense but not in active.

> 1) I have bought a house.
>
> 2) A house has been bought by me.

Comment: "To be + p.p." passive formula. "Have/has + p.p." present perfect formula. Now if we use passive formula in present perfect formula we should use the p.p form of "to be" which is "been" ---> "have/has + been+ p.p." present perfect passive.

Comment: *. . . has been bought by **me***. Prepositions take the object form of pronouns, not the possessive form.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, look at a sentence in the present tense:

> I love her

To put that into passive mood, we

1. move the object to the start of the sentence
2. convert the verb ("love") to a passive participle — that's a kind of adjective. We then need to 3) add a verb **be** to join the original object to the passive participle.

> She **is** loved

A verb in present perfect simple is **have + past participle**, for example ***have bought***. To convert a present perfect simple sentence to passive voice, we

1. move the object to the start of the sentence,
2. convert the verb to a passive participle (which is the same as the past participle) and
3. insert the past participle of **be**, which is **been**.

> I have bought a house
>
> A house has **been** bought by me.